# c++ static-only class allocation

Tags: c++, static, allocation

I know how to prevent heap allocation of a class (make new and new[] private).
I know how to prevent stack and static allocations (make destructor private).

I am wondering is there anyway to allow only static allocations at compile time?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want a set static configurator class instances that will be analyzed at start-up and I do not want instances of this to be created once start-up is done and I would like to have it flagged by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Sorry. Reason is that the static allocation places exact same requirements on the type as automatic allocation; it can't be distinguished.

However, you can prevent client code from instantiating your type, and provide access to one or more instances created by the type's own code.

Generally people often think that singletons etc. are a splendid idea, perhaps it confers some feeling of being in control, whatever, but anyway, what then happens is that at some point more general instantiation is needed, and all that work was not just wasted but then actively generates more … and completely needless … work.

So general advice is, as for premature optimization, don't do it.

Although in some cases it can be the right solution.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a namespace? There's no reason to wrap something in a class if you're only ever going to have a static instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to force all instances of a class to be static. Could you create a class with exclusively static members instead?

In my opinion, this is better than using a `namespace`, because namespaces cannot have private members.

Comment: An anonymous namespace is essentially private to the compilation unit. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Why do you need to expose all of the implementation details to the entire compilation unit? Even if this namespace were in a compilation unit by itself, I see no benefit to using an anonymous namespace vs. using a class with exclusively static members. I may be wrong; it wouldn't be the first time!

Comment: Cowboy: but then there's only one copy of the data, which exceeds the OP's requirement.